# SQL MIN and MAX results with added DISTINCT operator in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having some difficulty (have not written queries in years) getting the result set I am after.  My table itemdata looks like this:

```
year make model
1972 foo  bar
1973 foo  bar
1975 foo  bar
1971 bar  foo
1972 bar  foo
1973 bar  foo
1974 bar  foo
1975 bar  foo
1976 bar  foo
```

My goal is to return a result set consisiting of the distinct make model pairs with a start year and an end year like so:

```
startyear endyear make model
1972      1975    foo  bar
1971      1976    bar  foo
```

For some reason (lack of SQL knowledge being the most likely) I'm not getting the result set I want.  I've tried a number of queries and I thought I would succeed with:

```
SELECT MIN(year) as startyear , MAX(year) as endyear, make, model 
FROM itemdata 
WHERE model = (SELECT DISTINCT model FROM itemdata)
```

...however my subquery returning with multiple rows errored out the query.

I'd appreciate any help or advice!

Answer (score 2):

Use a GROUP BY on make and model instead, and that should get you what you need.

```
SELECT MIN(year) AS startyear, MAX(year) as endyear, make, model
FROM itemdata GROUP BY make, model;
```

Comment: While I feel like an idiot for having stuck to the DISTINCT method, I'm very thankful that you've solved my problem so quickly.  Much appreciated!