# Distinct Column gives incorrect results

Tags: mysql

I am using DISTINCT in query and wants to use MIN and MAX functions too.

Just by using DISTINCT it gives proper result count: 1348

But if I add MIN() and MAX() Function in query then it returns one record having MAX column.
I want all those records proper but need to find MAX amount from price column as well.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*, (a.price * 1) as calculatedPrice, 
                py.package_id as py_package_id
FROM qd_posts as a
INNER JOIN qd_categories as c ON c.id=a.category_id AND c.active=1
LEFT JOIN qd_categories as cp ON cp.id=c.parent_id AND cp.active=1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) max_id, post_id FROM qd_payments WHERE active=1 GROUP BY post_id) mpy ON mpy.post_id = a.id AND a.featured=1
LEFT JOIN qd_payments as py ON py.id=mpy.max_id
LEFT JOIN qd_packages as p ON p.id=py.package_id
WHERE a.country_code = 'CA' 
       AND (a.verified_email = 1 AND a.verified_phone = 1) 
       AND a.archived != 1 
       AND a.deleted_at IS NULL
ORDER BY p.lft DESC, a.created_at DESC
```

After adding MAX to query

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*, (a.price * 1) as calculatedPrice, 
       py.package_id as py_package_id, 
       MAX(a.price) as maxprice
FROM qd_posts as a
INNER JOIN qd_categories as c ON c.id=a.category_id AND c.active=1
LEFT JOIN qd_categories as cp ON cp.id=c.parent_id AND cp.active=1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) max_id, post_id FROM qd_payments WHERE active=1 GROUP BY post_id) mpy ON mpy.post_id = a.id AND a.featured=1
LEFT JOIN qd_payments as py ON py.id=mpy.max_id
LEFT JOIN qd_packages as p ON p.id=py.package_id
WHERE a.country_code = 'CA' 
       AND (a.verified_email = 1 AND a.verified_phone = 1) 
       AND a.archived != 1 AND a.deleted_at IS NULL
ORDER BY p.lft DESC, a.created_at DESC
```

Not sure what to do next.

Comment: Could you please explain a little clearer what the problem you're trying to solve please? I'm not sure what end result you are expecting :)

Comment: basically I want all 1348 records but also maximum value as well

Comment: can you share your laravel query if any ?

Comment: Share some of example data in your table, and output for both queries with desired output

Comment: I suspect you will need to use GROUP BY here, instead of DISCTINCT, but i'm not yet sure how exactly.

Comment: The maximum value of which column? @BitsPlease

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129331/sql-min-and-max-results-with-added-distinct-operator-in-mysql

check this if it helps

Comment: price I want maximum price value

Comment: 'If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

You could clarify this question by including some sample data. Basically I suspect you need a sub query to get the max. for example

```
drop table if exists t;

create table t
(pid int, price int);

insert into t values
(1,10),(1,20);

select distinct t.pid, (select max(price) from t t1 where t1.pid = t.pid) maxprice
from t;

+------+----------+
| pid  | maxprice |
+------+----------+
|    1 |       20 |
+------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The use of a distinct with a.* may cause your query to output multiple rows because distinct is over all the columns selected.